# link list node in C, struct prototype

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am working on an embedded system and I need to implement a linked list.

So I used a struct to construct a node

```
typedef struct A
{
   ... //some data
   struct A *next;
   struct A *prev;
} A;
```

I think on PC (gcc) this works fine. However, the embedded system compiler complains that "identifier A is not declared"...

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which embedded compiler are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add a separate *forward declaration* of the struct:

```
struct A;
typedef struct A
{
    ... //some data
    struct A *next;
    struct A *prev;
} A;
```

Some compilers do take your definition the way you posted it, but I've seen older compilers that require a separate forward declaration. This may be related to an older standard, or an incomplete standard implementation. In fact, on a project where we needed to write code that runs on five platforms with different compilers, we made it a companywide coding standard requirement to have the forward declaration separate from the struct's typedef.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it out:

```
typedef struct A A;

struct A {
   ... //some data
   struct A *next;
   struct A *prev;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code should compile just fine. You are probably using a non-standard compiler. As an alternative to the other suggestions, you can try this code:

```
typedef struct a
{
   ... //some data
   struct a *next;
   struct a *prev;
} A;
```

This way, you shouldn't need a forward declaration.

Comment: Oh btw, if you compile the original code in a C++ compiler, it won't work. C++ handles struct namespaces different than C.